# makefile conditionals

Tags: include, makefile, conditional-statements

Note: using MinGW's make (should be GNU make)

i have a couple of `-include` statements in my makefile to import dependencies which were generated using `g++ -MM`. However I would like to only do this when necessary. I have several different build targets and I don't want all of their respective dependency files to be included since this takes a while (suppose I'm running `make clean`: no need to include them in this case)

Here's the format of my makefile.

```
DEPS_debug = $(patsubst %.cpp,build_debug/%.d,$(SRC))
OBJ_debug = $(patsubst %.cpp,build_debug/%.o,$(SRC))
all: program_debug
    -include $(DEPS_debug) #make: include: Command not found
program_debug: $(OBJ_debug)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_debug) -o $@
```

Comment: It's rather unclear what you want, or why the `include` line doesn't do whatever it is that you want. For automatically-generated dependency information, that `include` line does exactly what *I* would want... perhaps that is because I am using -MMD -MP (inline generation) instead of -MM (extra pass for dependencies).

Comment: I want to `-include $(DEPS_debug)` only when making target `all` and not when making target `clean` or target `release` for instance. Currently, putting it in there has make trying to run `include` from the shell rather than its built-in include function.

Comment: See my answer below. Your first error is TAB-ing the `include`, your second is trying to make it conditional in the first place. You simply don't have to. It doesn't even speed up things - `make` has to check the directory contents anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to include those files needlessly, you have a couple of options:

You can put in a conditional as Diego Sevilla suggests (but I would recommend using `MAKECMDGOALS` so that you can write a more flexible version, specific to targets, e.g. you'll include `foo.d` if and only if you're making `foo.o`).

You can use make recursively (heresy!), invoking `$(MAKE)` for each target object, using a makefile that includes that target's dependencies.

But actually *including* the file takes negligible time, it's the *rebuilding* of the file (automatic for any included file that's out of date) that takes time.
If needless rebuilding is what you want to avoid, you can use a [very clever trick](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html). When must `foo.d` be rebuilt? Only when something about `foo` has changed. But in that case `foo.o` must also be rebuilt. So don't have a seperate rule for `foo.d`, just rebuild it as a side effect of making `foo.o`. That way you can include all dependency files and not waste time rebuilding them if they aren't needed.

**EDIT:**
I'm astounded that merely *including* these files can add 2-3 seconds to `make clean`. My last paragraph is off the mark, so let me expand on the first two options.

If `all` is the only target for which these files should be included, and you `make all` from the command line (and not e.g. `make all tests tarball install kitchenSink`), then this will do it:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),all)
-include $(DEPS_debug)
endif
```

Note that this will *not* include `foo.d` if you `make foo.o`. You can write a more sophisticated conditional, something like

```
$(foreach targ,$(MAKECMDGOALS),$(eval $(call include_deps $(targ)))...
```

but that's pretty advanced, so let's get a simple version working first.

If you'd rather avoid the conditional and use recursive Make, the simplest way is to split the makefile in two:

makefile:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -f makefile.all

clean:
    rm whatever

...other rules
```

makefile.all:

```
DEPS_debug = $(patsubst %.cpp,build_debug/%.d,$(SRC))
OBJ_debug = $(patsubst %.cpp,build_debug/%.o,$(SRC))
-include $(DEPS_debug)

all: program_debug
program_debug: $(OBJ_debug)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_debug) -o $@
```

Comment: It is my fault that I didn't include the format of my makefile more comprehensively, as I am already doing exactly what you speak of in your last paragraph, I generate my .d files at the same time that I build my .o's.

Comment: @Steven Liu: really? And you find that just *including* unneeded `.d` files significantly slows down `make clean`? How many files are we talking about, and how many seconds of delay?

Comment: About 2-3 seconds on an Atom netbook. I kept wondering why `make clean` took so long.

Comment: @Steven Lu: Apologizes from me, too, for adamantly claiming that you don't need to make the inclusion conditionally. +1 to Beta's answer.

Comment: recursive make looks really clean and nice. Two thumbs up!

Comment: With recursive make I don't think I'll need to do multiple versions of `CFLAGS` and several other variable-lists (I had one for each target). It's great!

Comment: @Steven Lu: Please note the "heresy!"... recursive make is considered bad practice by many. Google for "recursive make considered harmful".

Comment: I have ran into some problems already. But it's for another question.

Answer (score 1):

`include`s are independent of the rules, as they are makefile indications, not compilation indications. You can, however, use makefile conditionals based on special makefile variables such as `MAKECMDGOALS`, that is set to the default goal:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),all)
    -include whatever
endif
```

This is included when no default goal is specified. You can change the condition to specify the exact goal you want to check to include other sub-makefiles.

Comment: I did some testing and it seems like `ifeq ($(.DEFAULT_GOAL),)` results in true even when I run `make clean`.

Comment: I think that this approach will work, but `.DEFAULT_GOAL` is not the best choice. Take a look at `MAKECMDGOALS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Indenting a line by a TAB makes `make` think it's a command to be passed to the shell (as you found out). It doesn't work that way.

The `-` in front of `include` suppresses errors that might result from `DEPS_debug` not existing (e.g. when running `clean` or `release` without having had a dependency-file-generating call first). Since `DEPS_debug` is not a dependency of those rules (`clean` / `release`), your dependency files do not get generated when you call them, and everything is fine. I don't really see the problem you're having - you don't *have* to make the include conditional.

Perhaps you'd like to change your approach, though. Instead of having a seperate `*.d` target, with a seperate `-M` preprocessor pass, you might want to try something like `-MMD -MP` which generates the dependency files inline during code generation, in your standard *.c -> *.o pass.

(I know this sounds completely wrong at first, but when you think about it, it makes sense. Makefile logic is a bit backwards that way, unless you're familiar with functional programming.)